# UIMapView does not show content at first time

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, navigationcontroller

I have a ViewController has a UIMapView as IBOutlet and the ViewController will be pushed into a navigationViewController. I use loadHtmlString:baseURL: method to set the content of the UIMapView, which works fine. **But** the content does not show at the first time when I pushed the ViewController to the NavigationViewController

```
    [richContent loadHTMLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:template, 
      article.articleTitle, 
      stringFromDate, 
      article.bigImage, 
      html] 
  baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Dunno where is the problem...

Thanks.